# mathastext package: \ell undefined control sequence

Tags: mathastext

I'm using the `mathastext` package in order to get a sans math font throughout the document.

Unfortunately then the `\ell` command is undefined. Is there any way, to get this back, e.g. with unicode usage, but how?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\usepackage[symbolgreek,defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
\renewcommand\familydefault\rmdefault

\begin{document}
$\ell$
\end{document}
```

Comment: this bug is fixed in `mathastext 1.3h`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This restores an `\ell` whether it fits well with your font choice I leave for you to judge:-)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\let\xell\ell
\usepackage[symbolgreek,defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
\let\ell\xell
\renewcommand\familydefault\rmdefault

\begin{document}
$\ell$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, simple and just what I needed. Thanks a lot.